# GREP: Format PART of a paragraph in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, style, grep, paragraph

I am trying to format a part of a paragraph (I have the paragraph style) with GREP.

It is the caption of some photos, and the phrases are divided by the sign of "|":

`This is phrase 1 | This is phrase 2`

I would like to use GREP to style only phrase 1 (with character style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this GREP expression to select the first phrase:

`.+(?= \|)`

[image]

Let's have a look at the individual parts of the expression.

- `.+`
  This searches for *Any Character* `.` repeated *One or More Times* `+`.
- `(?= \|)`
  This is a *Positive Lookahead* which searches for text that comes *before* a space followed by a vertical bar  `\|`. We need to unescape the `|` with a `\` because it has a special use in GREP.

So the expression is searching for: *One or more characters that comes before a space followed by a vertical bar*.

#### Bonus tip

Add a *GREP Style* to the *Paragraph Style* to automatically format all instances of phrase 1 with a certain *Character Style*. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Wolf! but I was wrong to point to the text, the correct is: 
This is phrase 1 | This is phrase 2
it does not include parentheses. 
Tried testing the theory but I think I'm still a GREP beginner.
EDIT
I do it!
(?<=.).+(?= \|)

Thanks again, Wolf!

Comment: Ah. You shouldn't have included the parentheses in the code formatting then. Can't you just use `.+(?=\|)`? One or more characters before a space followed by a vertical bar.

Comment: Yes! Working great.
My code was not selecting the first letter.
Thanks again, @wolf.

Comment: OK, I have edited your question for you. I will also edit this answer accordingly. Please remember to *accept* it at some point. 